# Deserialization of Untrusted Data from XML or JSON

Tags: java, json, xml, security, serialization

I know deserialization can be vulnerable when an object is serialized with the standard "Serializable" interface (refer to [this](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/502.html)). But is this vulnerability applied when an object is serialized to XML or JSON? And if it is, how does that happen?
I can't really see how that could happen, so I would appreciate some examples.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That quite specifically depends on the serialization library that you use to deserialize objects and often the parameters used, so it's hard to provide a single answer.

As to "is it possible", yes, it's possible. Here's a sample exploit for XStream, for example:

http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/12/xstream-remote-code-execution-exploit.html

Comment: Thank you for tha fast reply. Is there any known sanitizer for XStream?

Comment: There’s a recommendation at the end of the article :)

Answer (score 0):

A general chat around the topic follows:

A good defence against bad data is to use a serialisation technology that allows one to write a full specification. By full specification, I mean not only the structure / content of objects, but that every value field's valid range can be specified, and every list/array length specified.

There's not many that do this. ASN.1, XSD (XML), and AFAIK JSON schemas can all have value and size constraints. Interestingly there is a formally defined translation between ASN.1 and XSD schemas.

It's then down to whether or not the tools you use actually do anything with these. Most of the ASN.1 tools I've seen do this very well, and will also tell you if you're trying to serialise an object that doesn't conform to the schema. The idea is that bad data is rejected as its read (so you never get an invalid object in memory) and you can never accidentally send / write bad data yourself, even if you wanted to.

Some XSD tools do constraints checking. I think xsd2code++ does. AFAIK xsd.exe from Microsoft does not.

I'm not so familiar with the land of JSON, but as far as I can tell one tends to read in whole objects and then compare them to the schema (which strikes me as being "too late"), rather than have some autogenerated code read the data and check it for you as it does so. When serialising objects it's up to the programmer to compare the result to the schema.

In contrast, technologies like Google Protocol Buffers don't let you do constraints checking at all. With GPB the best you can do is comment the .proto file and hope developers read it.

The code first approach, directly writing serialisable classes in C# / Java can do constraints checks, but only if you write the code yourself.

**Useful Old Technology**

Of all the serialisations I've ever used, by far the most rigorous has been ASN.1 (using decent ASN.1 tools). It's old and very telecommunications-ish (late 1980s, from the ITU; if you have trouble sleeping, go read one of their standards). However, despite its age it's still bang up to date, continually evolving.

For example, since it's original days it has grown several surprisingly modern wire formats; XML and JSON. Yes that's right; you can have an ASN.1 schema that gets compiled to code (C++, Java, C#) that will serialise to XML or JSON data formats (as well as ASN.1's more traditional binary formats like BER, uPER, etc).

The constraints rigour and the data format flexibility is surprisingly useful; you can receive some ultra-compact bit encoded uPER message from a radio, have it constraints checked as you read it, and then pass it on elsewhere as JSON/XML, all without having to write any code by hand.

When it comes to complex systems integration problems, I've not found anything to beat it.

[Useful old technology](https://www.thanassis.space/asn1.html)